# What will be the design of last layer of my CNN network?

Tags: python, keras-layer

I am trying to predict total number of items in videos. And every video have different number of items in it? I want to do it by 2dcnn. But i am confused that what exactly will be design of my last layer. I mean i dont have same length label list? For example if i have to design dense as last layer what could be the design? Dense(nodes=?)
Note: I have csv containing total number of items in the video against each training video.

Comment: If you train one cnn for all the videos, you should have all the classes that you want to identify in your last layer

Comment: Okayy.. but for example i have 3 videos and 70,30,28 respectively are the total number of items in each video. Then what i will mention in last layer.

Comment: You need all objects, if the 70, 30 and 28 objects are all different objects, you need 128 classes. If The 30 Objects in video 2 also appear in Video 1 with 70 objects, you don't need them extra...But I actually wonder what your training data look like and how you detect the objects but not just classify the single frames..

Comment: I am taking 30 frames from each video.. and the total number basically were collected from each frame of video. For evry frame number of objects may be same or different..  every frame have total number of objects against it in csv.

Comment: ah so this is planned as a regression task then and not a classification one? Then you'll have one output parameter: your number of objects. But I dont know if this can be a sucessful way.